# obtener lista de nombres de items en un treeview (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

quisiera obtener en una colección con todos los nombres de los items que anteceden al `subitem10`
es decir :  `list=[name0,subname0,subname10]`cuando seleccionamos `subitem10`.

Es para que al momento de seleccionar `subitem10` la lista que mencione ,interactue. Por eso la necesito.Un saludo.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import  tkinter as tk
raiz=tk.Tk()



tree=ttk.Treeview(raiz )
tree.config(height=22)
tree.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=8)

#items
for i in range(4):
    tree.insert('',i,f'item{i}',text=f'name{i}')

#subitems
for i in range(3):
    tree.insert('item0',i,f'subitem{i}',text=f'subname{i}')

#subitems1
for i in range(3):
    tree.insert('subitem0',i,f'subitem1{i}',text=f'subname1{i}')


raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aprovecharte de que le método `TreeView.select()` retorna la id del widget seleccionado y que `TreeView.parent(id)` retorna la id del widget padre si lo tiene o una cadena vacía si no hay widget padre. Si repites la operación hasta encontrar el widget sin padre tendrás la lista de ascendentes completa:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


def on_tree_item_select(event):
    item_id = tree.selection()[0]
    items_text = [tree.item(item_id)["text"]]
    while item_id:= tree.parent(item_id):
        items_text.insert(0, tree.item(item_id)["text"])
    print(items_text)


raiz = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(raiz )
tree.config(height=22)
tree.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=8)

#items
for i in range(4):
    tree.insert('', i, f'item{i}', text=f'name{i}')

#subitems
for i in range(3):
    tree.insert('item0', i, f'subitem{i}', text=f'subname{i}')

#subitems1
for i in range(3):
    tree.insert('subitem0', i, f'subitem1{i}', text=f'subname1{i}')

tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', on_tree_item_select)

raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se usa Python < 3.8, sin expresiones de asignación, el ciclo debería ser algo así:

```
def on_tree_item_select(event):
    item_id = tree.selection()[0]
    items_text = [tree.item(item_id)["text"]]
    while True:
        item_id = tree.parent(item_id)
        if not item_id:
            break
        items_text.insert(0, tree.item(item_id)["text"])
    print(items_text)
```

Comment: quisiera preguntarte como pudiese obtener las lista completa de todos los subelementos, es decir cuando das click en "Subname12", cómo pudiera obtener la lista de todos los elementos hasta llegar al encabezado o padre.